# Render view using response object

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am working on a project in symfony 3 and I have the following code which returns an instance of Response

```
public function dashboardAction()
{
    return parent::dashboardAction();
}
```

The parent method of the above code is:

```
public function dashboardAction()
{
    $blocks = [
        'top' => [],
        'left' => [],
        'center' => [],
        'right' => [],
        'bottom' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($this->container->getParameter('sonata.admin.configuration.dashboard_blocks') as $block) {
        $blocks[$block['position']][] = $block;
    }

    $parameters = [
        'base_template' => $this->getBaseTemplate(),
        'admin_pool' => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool'),
        'blocks' => $blocks,
    ];

    if (!$this->getCurrentRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $parameters['breadcrumbs_builder'] = $this->get('sonata.admin.breadcrumbs_builder');
    }

    return $this->render($this->getAdminPool()->getTemplate('dashboard'), $parameters);
}
```

I would like to pass a variable `articles` to the view in the instance of the Response.

I tried doing something like this

```
return $this->render(parent::dashboardAction(), array(
        'articles' => $articles,
    ));
```

But it does not work. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->render` returns a Response object and the first parameter is the name of a template to render (a string). You are trying to pass the Response object as first parameter to `render` again, which obviously can't work.

Also `$this->render` literally renders the template with the parameters provided. That means the return value of your parent dashboardAction returns a response object containing the rendered HTML of the template returned by `$this->getAdminPool()->getTemplate('dashboard')`. There is no way you can change the rendered HTML at that point if you don't want to actually work with the completely rendered HTML (no, you don't want to).

In general I don't think it is a good idea to reuse action methods directly. Instead you can do the following:

Create a method `getDashboardParameters` in your parent class, which only returns the parameters for the render function, but does not call `render`.

```php
protected function getDashboardParameters()
{
    $blocks = [
        'top' => [],
        'left' => [],
        'center' => [],
        'right' => [],
        'bottom' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($this->container->getParameter('sonata.admin.configuration.dashboard_blocks') as $block) {
        $blocks[$block['position']][] = $block;
    }

    $parameters = [
        'base_template' => $this->getBaseTemplate(),
        'admin_pool' => $this->container->get('sonata.admin.pool'),
        'blocks' => $blocks,
    ];

    if (!$this->getCurrentRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $parameters['breadcrumbs_builder'] = $this->get('sonata.admin.breadcrumbs_builder');
    }

    return $parameters;
}
```

Change your parent dashboardAction to look like this:

```php
public function dashboardAction() {
    return $this->render($this->getAdminPool()->getTemplate('dashboard'), $this->getDashboardParameters());
}
```

Change your child dashboardAction to look like this:

```php
public function dashboardAction() {
    $parameters = $this->getDashboardParameters();
    $parameters['articles'] = $articles;
    return $this->render($this->getAdminPool()->getTemplate('dashboard'), $parameters);
}
```